# Nested Flexbox breaks in IE11

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I can't find a way to get this to work. I have a tile that has two main parts:

[image]

This layout works everywhere except IE11, I think because I have a nested flexbox.

The outer flexbox is as follows:
[image]

Green is flex:1 and yellow is flex:0.

Here is the inner flexbox, which lives inside the green flexbox. It is another simple flex:1/flex:0 layout, just like the outer flexbox.
[image]

In IE11, the inner flexbox pushes everything else off the screen:
[image]

I need to support IE11, and I feel like I am missing a simple workaround.

Please help!

Comment: here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/jkies00/pen/EewZyX

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the _"shortest code necessary to reproduce it"_ **in the question itself**. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: And making a sample in Codepen or Fiddle is useless when it comes to IE11, as neither work in it, a Stack snippet does work in IE11.

Comment: **What breaks your layout here in IE11 is `flex:0;`** *(what did you really mean here ? )* remove it, for the rest *(flex:1; ain't really needed for IE11 here )*, let the browser do the math itself as much as possible. too much flex kills flex .   https://codepen.io/layedhere/full/xaWzXy/ If you think this answers your trouble let us know .

Comment: regarding useless codepen, sorry, here is one that will run in IE 11: https://s.codepen.io/jkies00/debug/EewZyX/ZoMBaKLGeqLk

Comment: pen can be seen in full page in genuine IE11 . here is a screen of yours and mine side by side in IE11. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojTai.jpg did you check mine earlier in IE11 ?

Comment: just noticed you update yours, but the bug is still there ... (screenshot posted in ealier comment) . too much flex: xxx ; kills it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE11 requires an unit in flex-basis (3rd value of flex property) and according to [source](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common), when you set `flex: 1` it actually equals to `flex: 1 1 0`.

Try changing each of the `flex` properties from `flex: X` to `flex: X 1 auto`

Comment: @LGSon Edited my answer, thanks for suggestions. :)

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the [CanIUse page about flex](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), we can read:

> - IE 11 requires a unit to be added to the third argument, the flex-basis property see MSFT documentation
>
>   - In IE10 and IE11, containers with display: flex and flex-direction: column will not properly calculate their flexed childrens' sizes if the container has min-height but no explicit height property. See bug.
>   - IE 11 does not vertically align items correctly when min-height is used see bug

Try to tweak some of your css to not face those bugs by being more specific on your `flex` declarations.